# How to use developerPayload in react-native-iap

Tags: react-native-iap

I'm trying to provide a Google subscription service using the `react-native-iap` API.

I'm trying to enter data into the `developerPayload` value to split the service.

```js
const result = await requestSubscription(
      sku,
      false,
      offerToken,
      developerPayload,
    );
```

ChatGPT told me to use it as above.
However, there is no function in their API that takes the arguments as listed.

How can I use it?

API version :`12.10.2`

Thank you for read my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle the Android and iOS separately on your own business logic.

You can simply check the `Platform.OS === 'android'` and then use the `IAP.requestSubscription` depends on this and write two different methods for these.

Here is a basic example for you:

Android Example:

```js
export async const purchaseAndroidSubscription(sku: string, offerToken: string){
 await IAP.requestSubscription({
      sku,
      subscriptionOffers: [
        {
          sku,
          offerToken,
        },
      ],
 });
}
```

iOS one:

```js
export async const purchaseAppleSubscription(sku: IOSSku){
    await IAP.clearTransactionIOS();
    await IAP.requestSubscription({ sku });
}
```

You should customize/change as your need.

Also, I strongly suggest you to read the whole [documentation](https://react-native-iap.dooboolab.com/docs/get-started) and check the [IAPExample](https://github.com/dooboolab-community/react-native-iap/tree/main/IapExample) before doing these stuff. Only ChatGPT will not enough for this :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the code you wrote doesn't have a `developerPayload`, does that mean I can't use it?

Comment: `requestSubscription` does not have a developerPayload. 

You can use `finishTransaction` for `developerPayloadAndroid`. 

It does not have a this for iOS, only for Android. 

You should check `react-native-iap`'s documentation for best-practices and how to use it properly

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look for the documentation.